# Create dynamic finder between two classes in Grails

Tags: grails, dynamic-finders

I have two domain classes (db tables) in my Grails project:

```
class Doctor {
String role;
String name;
String surname;
String address;
 ...


@NotNull
static belongsTo = [secUser:SecUser]
....
}



class SecUser {

transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
...

}
```

I would like to find all SecUser that have not a correspondent Doctor.

How can I do it?

Comment: What properties do Doctor and SecUser have to link them together?  I don't think you provide enough information.

Comment: Doctor belnogsTo Secuser...I think it is enough...what do you need to know also?

Comment: You need to show a property linking Doctor and Secuser or else how can anybody help you write an HQL query?  This is not enough information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
SecUser.executeQuery(" FROM SecUser secUser WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT doctor.SecUser FROM Doctor doctor")
```